# Yii2 DI container: registering same class twice, but with different constructor parameters

Tags: php, dependency-injection, yii2

In my project I use Yii2 native dependency injection container which is being set in application bootstrap file.
What I want to achieve is to inject same class twice, but with different constructor parameters:

```
Yii::$container->set(
    'common\components\ElasticSearchClient',
    [],
    [$elasticSearchServer1Params]
);

Yii::$container->set(
    'common\components\ElasticSearchClient',
    [],
    [$elasticSearchServer2Params]
);
```

Later those elastic search client class objects should be injected automatically into other classes as following:

```
class SomeClass1
{
    /**
     * @var ElasticSearch
     */
    protected $elasticSearchClient1;

    public function __construct(\common\components\ElasticSearchClient $elasticSearchClient1) {
        $this->elasticSearchClient1 = $elasticSearchClient1;
    }
}

class SomeClass2
{
    /**
     * @var ElasticSearch
     */
    protected $elasticSearchClient2;

    public function __construct(\common\components\ElasticSearchClient $elasticSearchClient2) {
        $this->elasticSearchClient2 = $elasticSearchClient2;
    }
}
```

So is it possible to do so? Should I use DI container aliases somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use aliases for components in the Dependency Injection Container. For example:

Add a component to DI container:

```
Yii::$container->set(
    'component1',
    [
        'class' => '\common\components\ElasticSearchClient'
    ],
    [$elasticSearchServer1Params]    
);
```

Get the component from DI container

```
$component = Yii::container->get('component1');
$someObject = new SomeClass1($component);
```

But the more clear way to solve this task is registration of one ElasticSearchClient component and its configuration before creating of SomeClass

```
// add the component to the container
Yii::$container->set(
    'common\components\ElasticSearchClient',
);

// get the component from container and configure it
Yii::$container->get('common\components\ElasticSearchClient', 
                     [], 
                     [$elasticSearchServer1Params]
);
$someObject = new SomeClass1($component);
```

Also, you can register SomeClass1 and SomeClass2 in DI container for easier create them.

```
$container->set('SomeClass1', function ($container, $params, $config) {
    $searchClient = $contaier->get('common\components\ElasticSearchClient',
                                   [], 
                                   [$elasticSearchServer1Params]
    );
    return new SomeClass1($searchClient);
});

$container->set('SomeClass2', function ($container, $params, $config) {
    $searchClient = $contaier->get('common\components\ElasticSearchClient',
                                   [], 
                                   [$elasticSearchServer2Params]
    );
    return new SomeClass2($searchClient);;
});
```